# How to specify X11 SouthEast gravity for Emacs X windoes?

Tags: emacs, x11, gravity

This is currently specific to Emacs, but if there's a generic answer for X applications in general I'd love it.

Is there an X resource I can set for Emacs that will set the gravity of its main windows to SouthEast?  That is, when I start up a new Emacs session, I want its window to appear as close as possible to the lower-right corner of the screen (modulo the window manager's placement algorithms).

The window manager in question is Enlightenment E17, but window gravity is an X concept, is it not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a `-g -0-0` command-line argument?

If you want to specify it via Elisp, you can add frame parameters as in:

```
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(top . -))
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(left . -))
```

Comment: Close, but that ignores any of the window manager's structures.  *I.e.*, the new window might end up behind an always-on-top taskbar.  But it's a place to start; thanks!

Comment: Okey, that's a non-starter after all -- regardless of where focus is located, the new window will end up in the corner of the **right-most** monitor.  I use a multi-headed configuration.